# Is [FIRApp configure] send statistics in DEBUG mode on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-analytics

[image]

I've added Firebase to my app.
If I run build in DEBUG mode - do firebase include my usage in overall statistics from other users in release mode?

And if so - how to send stats only in RELEASE mode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything will get included together.  Firebase doesn't care the mode in which your code was built - everything goes to the same project.

If you want to separate testing from production, you should instead create two different projects, one for test, and one for prod. Build your test builds against the the test project, and build your production builds (that only go to users) to your production project.  This will keep everything separate, and is the recommended configuration.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I should write like this?
`#ifndef DEBUG [FIRApp configure]; #endif`

Comment: No, I'm not saying you should build differently based on debug or release.  I'm saying you should build two different versions of your app, one for testing and one for production, and they should target different Firebase projects.

Comment: Got it. I don't have project for testing. Only 1 project for debug & release. I'm concerned that in debug stats gets send too.